# R Dygraphs DyRoller not plotting moving average

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am having difficulty in plotting moving average using the R dygraph package using DyRoller. As per the documentation, I should be able to plot moving average by entering a value in the lower window. However on entering any value for moving average above 1, I get an empty plot. 
Figure below shows the issue:

[image]

Below is the sample code for reproducing the problem:

```
require(xts)
require(dygraphs)
startDate = as.POSIXct("2013-12-23 9:30:00")
endDate = as.POSIXct("2013-12-23 16:00:00")
dateSeq5sec = seq(from=startDate, to=endDate, by="5 sec")     
data <- rnorm(4681,6,1)    
my_data <- data.frame(dateSeq5sec,data)    
my_data <- xts(my_data,order.by = my_data$dateSeq5sec)
dygraph(my_data, main = "Important Discoveries") %>% 
   dyRoller(showRoller = TRUE, rollPeriod = 1)
```

Comment: `dput` your data and share.

Comment: if you look at str(my_data) you will see that Data is character and not numeric..it could explain the problem

Comment: Thank you MLavoie. I converted the Data vector to numeric but still experiencing the same issue. I am trying multiple options. I will post what I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
dygraph( xts(x = data, order.by = dateSeq5sec) ) %>% 
   dyRoller(showRoller = TRUE, rollPeriod = 1)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much!